# file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I'm using the new OData4ObjC framework for IOS 6, but when I try to run it keeps telling me this error.

I have followed the instructions found here https://github.com/ElizabethDuncan/OData4ObjC.

I also changed the framework to an older one to see if that is the problem. I don't know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future, to check what architectures a library/executable is compiled for you should use the `lipo -info` command.  Like so:

> **mitchellge$** *lipo -info /Users/mitchellge/Downloads/libMSODataLib.a*
>   --> Architectures in the  fat file:
>   /Users/mitchellge/Downloads/libMSODataLib.a are: armv6 armv7

As you can see, the library (libMSODataLib.a) that is bundled with `OData4ObjC` is compiled for the **armv6** and **armv7** architectures and not the **armv7s**.  One fix is to go into your project's build settings and change `Valid Architectures` from `armv7 armv7s` to just `armv7`